# Pandas group by multiple columns and duplicate row with iteration

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, conditional-statements, rows

I have a pandas array that looks like the below image. I'd like to do the following:

1. Group rows by Exchange and Ticker (to ensure they are unique)
2. Create 4 copies of each row
3. For each row, set the year to a different value (from variable), 2017, 2016 etc

The aim is to show 5 years for history for each ticker, currently my table only has room for one year. I've researched this here however I couldn't find this combination. Thanks in advance!

[image]

I've partially solved this with the following:

```
# Create four copies of the dataframe
Yr2_df = df1
Yr3_df = df1
Yr4_df = df1
Yr5_df = df1

# Merge the 5 dataframe into one combined dataframe
df = pd.concat([df1, Yr2_df, Yr3_df, Yr4_df, Yr5_df],axis=0).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
```

However this does not provide the date range (each row should have a different year: 2017, 2016 etc). Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is how I added the date range. The challenge was cycling through the list of years as this was shorter than the list of rows.

```
# Define list of years
years = [Year_Minus_1, Year_Minus_2, Year_Minus_3, Year_Minus_4, Year_Minus_5]

# Define index for iteration
index = df.index

# Import library for advanced iteration
import itertools

# Iterate over index and list of years so that we have one row per year for each ticker
for i, y in zip(index, itertools.cycle(years)):
     df.iloc[i, df.columns.get_loc('Year')] = y
```